# zend connection to database with different host name

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-connection

I am using Zend Framework 1.12

I need to connect to database that is present in different Host "**abc.amazonaws.com**"

I tried with this but no success

My application.ini is

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0



resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.dbname = "taskmgr"
resources.db.params.username = "*******"
resources.db.params.password = "**********"
resources.db.params.host = "*********************.amazonaws.com"
resources.db.params.profiler = "true"




[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Can any body help me out of this,

**The application is ready Please guide me with minimal changes**

Comment: Any error messages or anything like that?

Comment: It is giving Application Error.Which I think that connection is not happen

Comment: You need a bit more to go on than that! Do you have the error log enabled?

Comment: **Resolved...** This methods works ...The Error was the table name were case sensitivity...